# How to generate dynamically blazor's @bind-Value?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor-server-side

I'm playing with Blazor and I'd like to create a dynamically generated form, which is part of a grid.
The entity type of the data is passed to the grid and this is the base of the form. The problem I'm facing now is `@bind-Value`, which is needed to be able to edit the given entity.

I use [BlazorStrap](https://blazorstrap.io/), and it is a Blazor Server Side project.

I have the following code in the razor file:

```
@{
string bind = $"{nameof(_editedItem)}.{propertyInfo.Name}";
}
<BSBasicInput InputType="InputType.Text"
              id="@propertyInfo.Name"
              @bind-Value="@bind"/>
```

The problematic part is the last line. Always the `_variableName.PropertyName` is displayed instead of pulling out the value from the object.

The proper code should look like this:

```
<BSBasicInput InputType="InputType.Text"
              id="@propertyInfo.Name"
              @bind-Value="_variableName.PropertyName"/>
```

What I tried so far:

- multiple flavors of the syntax, but, since I'm not really experienced with Razor syntax, after I while I hit a wall
- debugging shows that the vairable I'd like to edit gets its values, so the problem somewhere the generated `@bind-Value` value
- I also checked the generated code (the .g files), but I haven't found any smelly there (please, find it below)
- I haven't created yet a POC without dynamically generated forms, because it would take a few hours to create somthing similar complexity.

What is the solution here?

```
#nullable restore
#line 24 "/../..ModalEdit.razor"
                                                        bind

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                        , 31, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this,
__value => bind = __value, bind)));
                        __builder4.AddMarkupContent(32, "\n");
```

Answer (score 5):

you cant bind, but you can use callbacks and lambda functions to archive the same results:

```
            @if (user != null)
            {
                @foreach (var property in user.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    <Field>
                        <FieldLabel>@(property.Name): @(property.PropertyType.FullName)</FieldLabel>
                        @switch (property.PropertyType.FullName)@*Chose editing style*@
                        {
                            case "System.String":
                                <TextEdit Text="@property.GetValue(user)?.ToString()" TextChanged="value => property.SetValue(user, value)" />
                                break;
                            case "System.Boolean":
                                <Switch TValue="bool" Checked="(bool)property.GetValue(user)" CheckedChanged="value => property.SetValue(user, value)" />
                                break;
                            default: /*Unsuported/Not implemented editing*/
                                <TextEdit Text="@property.GetValue(user)?.ToString()" Disabled="true" />
                                break;
                        }
                    </Field>
                }
            }
```

I'm using Blazorise controls in this example, but you can use any.