# Blazor: Generate and bind input controls via reflection

Tags: forms, reflection, data-binding, blazor

I am new to Blazor/ASP.NET Core and wanted to generate a small formula based on a class with properties via reflection, so I only have to change the code in 1 place if I want to add/remove/change a property. For `bool` properties it should generate a HTML `checkbox` input, for `int` a `number` and for `string` a `text` input, which do validation.

The base code:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Example1
{
    [Required]
    public bool SomeBoolean { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid percentage, must be between 0 and 100.")]
    public int SomePercentage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "File Name too long (200 character limit).")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
@using System;
@using System.Reflection;

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Example1 Ex1 { get; set; } = new Data.Example1();

    [Parameter]
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The example data is valid.");
    }
}

<EditForm Model="@Ex1" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <table>
        @foreach (var property in typeof(Example1).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@property.Name:</td>
                <td>
                    @if (ReadOnly) {
                        @property.GetValue(Ex1)
                    } else {
                        // TODO: Generate input control here.
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <input type="submit" />
</EditForm>
```

My current attempt to get it working is the following: I copied what is generated into the `.g.cs` code file, when directly referencing a property, instead of using reflection, in either an `<input/InputCheckbox/InputNumber/InputText>` control and replaced the property access with the direct call to the getter or setter that is available via reflection.

```cs
@if (ReadOnly) {
    @property.GetValue(Ex1)
} else {
    <InputControl Parent="@this" Object="@Ex1" Property="@property" />
}
```

```cs
public class InputControl : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public object Parent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public object Object { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

        if (Parent == null || Object == null || Property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var i = 0;

        /*
        builder.OpenElement(i++, "input");
        builder.AddAttribute(i++, "id", Property.Name);
        */

        switch (Property.PropertyType.FullName)
        {
            case "System.Boolean":
                builder.OpenComponent<InputCheckbox>(i++);
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "Value", (bool)Property.GetValue(Object));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(Parent, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, v => Property.SetValue(Object, v), (bool)Property.GetValue(Object))));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "ValueExpression", (Expression<global::System.Func<bool>>)(() => (bool)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                /*
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "type", "checkbox");
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "checked", BindConverter.FormatValue((bool)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(Parent, v => Property.SetValue(Object, v), (bool)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("checked");
                */
                break;

            case "System.Int32":
                builder.OpenComponent<InputNumber<int>>(i++);
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "Value", (int)Property.GetValue(Object));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(Parent, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, v => Property.SetValue(Object, v), (int)Property.GetValue(Object))));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "ValueExpression", (Expression<global::System.Func<int>>)(() => (int)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                /*
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "type", "number");
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue((int)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(Parent, v => Property.SetValue(Object, v), (int)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
                */
                break;

            case "System.String":
                builder.OpenComponent<InputText>(i++);
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "Value", (string)Property.GetValue(Object));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(Parent, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, v => Property.SetValue(Object, v), (string)Property.GetValue(Object))));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "ValueExpression", (Expression<global::System.Func<string>>)(() => (string)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                /*
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "type", "text");
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue((string)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                builder.AddAttribute(i++, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(Parent, v => Property.SetValue(Object, v), (string)Property.GetValue(Object)));
                builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
                */
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException($"Unimplemented type `{Property.PropertyType.FullName}` in {nameof(InputControl)}.{nameof(BuildRenderTree)}!");
        }

        // builder.CloseElement();
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }
}
```

This throws an exception for what I think is created through `AddAttribute("ValueExpression")`: `ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a UnaryExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.`

Using the commented out code instead works for displaying and updating the values without an exception, but no validation for the input fields is happening (no red border), only when submitting the form via a button the bound data is validated and errors are only displayed in the `ValidationSummary` tag.

I think this question is somewhat related to [How to generate dynamically blazor's @bind-Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570685/how-to-generate-dynamically-blazors-bind-value) but I would like to use standard controls. How do I enable input validation?